# Blazor (Server Side) TextArea Fails With Long-ish Strings

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm writing a Blazor server side application for ETL.  I have a form with 8 fields, one of which is a textarea created with `<InputTextArea>`.  This field is used to cut-and-paste the contents of data from spreadsheets, CSV files, HTML tables, etc.

The `OnValidSubmit` for the `<EditForm>` is wired to a `ProcessForm()` function in the `@code {}` section of the `.razor` file.

Everything works fine as long as the string in the textarea is less than 20,798 characters.  When I paste 20,798 or more characters into the control, however, there is a pause on submission (the contents of the browser become disabled) then the message `An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded. Reload"` appears in the footer of the viewport.  I'm developing in VS Code, and nothing appears in the terminal window (or any other console window), including the logging statement at the very beginning of my `ProcessForm()` method.  However, the message `Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'` does appear on the JS console of the browser.

I've seen references to maximum buffer lengths in the underlying SignalR technology, but none of the methods I saw in older posts for setting a larger buffer appear compatible with new `.MapBlazorHub` method of configuring Blazor (and, in any event, I would like to be able to handle arbitrarily large amounts of data).

Does anyone know how I can increase, or remove, the data-size limit in this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is what you need. 32kb is the default as far as I can recall.

```
services
    .AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(options => { options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 32 * 1024; });
```

Comment: 32768 not 32 bytes

Comment: @GioviQ lol, good catch. I mindlessly copy pasted it to my application, realizing shortly after it said 32 bytes instead of kilobytes. I've modified the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem at today. This is caused because I am trying to send a message that is over the underlying default signalr limits, which are around 32 KB.

I found below solution.

Increase the `MaximumReceiveMessageSize` via `HubOptions`. Default value is 32 KB, but you can increase it like as below:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddHubOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024;  // KB
                });
```

if you want no limit, you set null value to MaximumReceiveMessageSize like as below:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddHubOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; // No size limit
                });
```

For more information, you can visit these links:

[Connection Closed Error and Attempting to Reconnect](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/common-connection-closed)

[Increase the Blazor SignalR Max Message Size](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/common-increase-signalr-max-message-size)